# Haskell Indention error that wont go away

Tags: haskell

Error is on the line `scoreH h b n`:

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

When I indent it by one space more (not in line with the function definition) I get

```
parse error on input =.
```

---

```
 scoreH :: Hand->DomBoard->Int->(Bool,[(Dom,End)]

 scoreH h b n = 
   let
     lPlays = leftdrops h b
     rPlays = rightdrops h b
     lPoss = leftScoreH lPlays b n
     rPoss = rightScoreH rPlays b n
   in
     if (length(lPoss) /= 0 || length(rPoss) /= 0) then (True,(lPoss++rPoss)) else (False,[(_,_)])


 rightScoreH :: Hand->DomBoard->Int->[(Dom,End)]

 rightScoreH [] _ _ = []

 rightScoreH (h:t) b n
    |scoreDom h R b == n = (h,R):rightScoreH t b n
    |otherwise = rightScoreH t b n

 leftScoreH :: Hand->DomBoard->Int->[(Dom,End)]

 leftScoreH [] _ _ = []

 leftScoreH (h:t) b n
    |scoreDom h L b == n = (h,L):leftScoreH t b n
    |otherwise = leftScoreH t b n
```

Comment: Please paste the exact code with original indentation and make it a code-box by marking and ctrl-k, otherwise we see different indentation from what you have and can't tell what the problem might be. (Or link to a HPaste/Gist, though it's generally discouraged to do that unless there's a good reason.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Oh wow, I had no idea about ctrl-k. I've been manually indenting everything this whole time... I looked for something like that before, too. That's not in the help page, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually this problem has nothing to do with indentation at all, it's right there in the first line: the signature is missing a closing paren.

```
                      (Bool,[(Dom,End)]   )
```

This would have been more obvious if you had left a bit more space in there, like

```
scoreH :: Hand -> DomBoard -> Int -> (Bool, [(Dom, End)]
                                     ⚡                  ⚡ clearly not closing
```